# How to Open the Excel Sheet stored at remote location in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to open the excel sheet using asp.net application. I have stored excel sheet on the different computer which is connected in network. I have tried following code but it is not working.

```
            addBatch.WA = new Excel.Application();

            addBatch.workbookPath = @"file:\\\\192.168.2.150\\Share\\Barcode_Details.xlsx";
            addBatch.excelWorkbook = WA.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

            addBatch.excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
            WA.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Have you tried `addBatch.workbookPath = @"\\192.168.2.150\Share\Barcode_Details.xlsx";`? An [`@` string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) does not require backslashes to be escaped.

Comment: @ Phylogenesis: Yes, I have tried That but it is not working

Comment: Then I suspect the share isn't accessible to the user the web service is running as.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/207671) knowledge base in order to setup permissions and IIS AppPool identities to access the network resource your trying to reach